# Continue while loop in Bash Script even if a condition fails

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
var="true"
i=1
while $var
do
  read -p "Enter value (true/false): " var
  if [[ $var == "true" ]]
  then
    echo "Iteration : $i"
    ((i++))
  elif [[ $var == "false" ]]
  then
    echo "Exiting the process"
  elif [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
  then
    echo "Invalid Choice."
    echo "Avaialable Choices are true or false"
    exit
  fi
done
```

Script is Working Fine. I Enter true the loop will iterate for false the script stops.
I want the script will continue asking "Enter Value" if any other value instead of true or false will be entered.

Comment: The `elif [[ $? -eq 1 ]]` isn't doing anything useful -- the `$?` it's checking is the exit status of the last command, which is `[[ $var == "false" ]]`, which clearly *did* fail or it wouldn't have gotten to this point. Just use a plain `else` instead. Also, your quoting reflexes are a bit backward; generally, static single-word strings without any special characters (like `true` and `false`) don't need to be quoted, but variable references like `$var` should be double-quoted to avoid weird parsing if they do contain weird characters.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : `$var` nees to be quoted only in the `while` line. It does not need to be quoted later, because we are inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @user1934428 True. I was going to point that out, but ran into the comment size limit. The reason I commented was that quoting simple fixed strings but not variable references suggests a basic misunderstanding of what quotes do in shell syntax. BTW, not quoting isn't always safe even in `[[ ]]` -- in `[[ $var1 = $var2 ]]`, `$var2` will be treated as a glob pattern unless it's double-quoted. The rules for when it's safe to leave off double-quotes are complex enough that I generally recommend double-quoting all var references unless there's a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

This would do the same with a more academic syntax:

```sh
i=0
while :; do
  printf 'Enter value (true/false): '
  read -r var
  case $var in
    true)
      i=$((i + 1))
      printf 'Iteration : %d\n' $i
      ;;
    false)
      printf 'Exiting the process\n'
      break
      ;;
    *)
      printf 'Invalid Choice.\nAvaialable Choices are true or false\n'
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find this to be a cleaner solution:

```
i=0
while true; do
  read -p "enter value: " myinput
  if [[ $myinput = true ]]; then
    echo "iteration $i"
    i=$((i+1))
  elif [[ $myinput = false ]]; then
    echo "exiting"
    exit
  else
    echo "invalid input"
  fi;
done;
```

The issue I see with your current code is that it is unclear which command's exit status $? refers to. Does it refer to the echo in the previous elif block? Or the last condition check? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in bash. I tried that:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [[ $var != "false" ]]
do
    read -p "Enter value (true/false): " var
    if [[ $var == "true" ]]
    then
    echo "Iteration : $i"
    ((i++))
    elif [[ $var == "false" ]]
    then
    echo "Exiting the process" 
    elif [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
    then
    echo "Invalid Choice."
    echo "Avaialable Choices are true or false"
    fi
done
```

I changed `while $var` with `while [[ $var ]]` because `while` works like `if`. It runs the given command. In there it is $var's value.

And I moved `exit` to first elif expression's end. So if user type false program will exit.